# Search sentence and replace for hyperlink in Word VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, ms-word

I trying to replace or search and add hyperlink to specyfy sentence in Word document. I try using this codes. Anyway code is changing only first finding word, not all in document:

```
       Dim r As Word.Range
    r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
    With r.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = ("MyWordA MyWordB")
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Forward = True
        .Execute()
        'If .Found = True Then r.Hyperlinks.Add(r, "http:\\www.whatever", , "Displayed text")
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            r.Hyperlinks.Add(r, "http:\\www.whatever", , "Displayed text")
            'r.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue 'works for all(?)
        Loop
    End With
```

Eaven when I want to find only single word in loop for, then code find first one:

```
    doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim r As Word.Range = doc.Range
    Dim ww As Word.Range
    For Each ww In r.Words
        If ww.Text = "MyWord" Then _
          ww.Hyperlinks.Add(ww, "http:\\www.whatever", , "Displayed text")
    Next
```

Anyone could tell me how I can search all text to replace/add hyperlinks to all text I was looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep finding the same text over and over again. Within your loop, after adding the hyperlink, you need to move the range *after* the added hyperlink. The simplest way to do this is to collapse the range by calling

```
r.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
```

To troubleshoot issues like this it is helpful to select the current range so that you can see what is going on.

```
Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True

    ' select range for troubleshooting
    r.Select()
    r.Hyperlinks.Add(r, "http:\\www.whatever", , "Displayed text")

    ' move the range after the link
    r.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
Loop
```